# Airpush ads for Android

Tags: android, ads

I want to implement Airpush ads in my app, but I want the users to be able to choose between Airpush ads and Mobclix ads.  The Permissions API from Airpush requires the user-encrypted IMEI.  The Android SDK returns the unencrypted IMEI, doesn't it?  Does anyone have some sample code for how I could implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: warning, several apps go banned for using airpush ads..still no word if its a androidnmarket TOS violation..but I would put off using airpush at this time

Comment: Thanks for the warning, I had read about a couple apps that had been pulled because of that, but thought it was still being discussed.  I was hoping to get some code ready so I could implement this when/if it is deemed okay.  It would default to mobclix ads and only enable Airpush if the user chooses to.

Comment: Airpush is in the process of implementing an opt-in system which they control. This isn't a good sign for them. Apps from the Android Market have been banned from using Airpush on terms that they exhibit malware-like behavior.

Comment: AirPush is *really* evil. I can only speak for myself but I know I would uninstall ANY application that used this.

Answer (score 1):

Apps were not getting banned exactly because of Airpush.  Google reinstated the one app that was banned for a day and said it is looking into the Airpush practices.  It's a good option if your users do not like in-app ads.  Give the user choices.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the imei to md5 (using the standard android md5 conversion function) before submitting it to the api.

Airpush is user opt-in now, nothing wrong with that...

Answer (score -1):

I worked with two people in an Android developers meetup last week and both are using Aipush. They were talking about the negative feedback they received, and the entire room came to the conclusion that almost all of the negative feedback was from the same person. Also almost 100 of the negative reviews had similar verbiage and terms not generally used by the common consumer or user.

Google should actually go after the writer of the comments. I have since posted a cheapo app on the market and I too received the same comments with the same verbiage. I don't think it is a spammer - just someone who hates Airpush and has a personal spite against them. Too bad because the push ads monetize great and no one complains when google+ or facebook send messages to your notification bar, only that one person.

Comment: Bullshit. That's an lame excuse for corporate management to lie to themselves, and keeping themselves and the shareholders believing no one complains about it. Just use Google, look at Forums. 10.000 of users are complaining about. And most will just write the same.

It's not possible for one user to have 100s of negative feedbacks, because you can only write comments on an device which installed it and only once per account. Keep believing your lies